Have Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2024 installed. I wrote a C# APP that uses MAPI to open Outlook but it only finds the 2013 install
My 2013 install of Outlook used to host an Epix email account and an Outlook account. The Outlook 2013 app stopped connecting with Outlook email account so I installed Outlook 2024 version 1.2024.1216.300 and added the Outlook account to that new Outlook version. A C# App I wrote still works fine in opening the Outlook 2013 but it can not find/access the Outlook 2024 install. The following code explores the issue:
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

// Log in to Outlook
   NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
   DebugWrite(outlookApp.Version.ToString(), bWriteMessage); //Returns 15.0.0.5603 (outlook 2013's version)
   outlookNamespace.Logon();
   DebugWrite(outlookNamespace.Accounts.Count.ToString(), bWriteMessage);//Returns 1(correct for 2013)
   DebugWrite(outlookNamespace.Stores.Count.ToString(),bWriteMessage);//Returns 3 (correct for 2013)
   foreach(Store store in outlookNamespace.Stores)
   {
        DebugWrite(store.DisplayName, bWriteMessage);
        DebugWrite(store.FilePath, bWriteMessage);
        DebugWrite(store.StoreID, bWriteMessage);
   }

Is there a way to access the Outlook 2024 install?

outlookApp where does that come from? Please show a [mcve]

Outlook 2013 is likely 32-bit. Did you install the 32-bit version of Outlook 2024 or the 64-bit version?

Charlieface - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

Then put that in your post. And where did you get Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook from? Is it a PIA or some other library?

1.2024.1216.300 sure looks like the version of the new web-based Outlook (Monarch). It does not expose any API except for the JS-based web addins.
